# ggmap package: making point sizes larger when scaled by a variable value?

Tags: r, ggmap

I'm using ggmap to plot incidence of sleeping sickness (HAT) in Malawi. I'm scaling point size by the number of cases, however the result is a map with tiny point sizes:

[image: Whole country map]

Zooming in (by adjusting the scale of the map) doesn't help.

This is my code:

```
malawi.map <- get_map(location = 'Malawi', zoom = 6)
gg <- ggmap(malawi.map)
gg <- gg + scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-17, -9))
gg <- gg + scale_x_continuous(limits = c(32,37))
malawi.Points1 <- gg + mynamestheme + labs(title = "2000-2004") + 
  geom_point(aes(x = Long, y = Lat, size = New_cases), 
             data = malawi_agg00.04, 
             alpha = .3, color = "red")
```

If you have any ideas on how to adjust this, they would be much appreciated.

Also, am I safe in assuming there's no way to remove the "Malawi" text from the map, other than to find a new basemap that doesn't have this?

Many thanks,
Julianne

Comment: Check out `scale_size()`. Increasing the range values from the default `c(1, 6)` will probably get you larger points.

Comment: Was your question answered, @JulianneMeisner?

Comment: It was, thank you so much @Roman! My apologies for being slow to report back

Answer (score 1):

You can try `scale_size()` for the point size and `get_googlemap()` with `style()` for the labels.

## Random data

```
malawi_agg00.04 <- data.frame("lon" = rnorm(50,33.5,0.5), 
                              "lat" = rnorm(50,-12,0.5), 
                              "new_cases" = rnorm(50,250,75))
```

## Getting a clean map

```
malawi.map <- get_googlemap(center = c(34.3015, -13.2543), 
                            zoom = 6, 
                            style = 'feature:administrative.country|element:labels|visibility:off')
```

## Setting the boundaries

```
gg <- ggmap(malawi.map)
gg <- gg + scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-17, -9))
gg <- gg + scale_x_continuous(limits = c(32,37))
```

## Plotting the points

```
gg + geom_point(aes(x = lon, y = lat, size = new_cases),
                data = malawi_agg00.04,
                alpha = .3, color = "red") +
     scale_size(range = c(2,6))
```

## Result

[image: malawi]